# Changing one object property in array of objects changes all object properties(TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the objects. The TypeModel object and the StatusModel object have one property `typeID` that must be one number(for example 1).

```
export class TypeModel{
        typeID: number;
        typeDescription: string;
    }


    export class StatusModel{
        typeId: number;
        statusId: number;
        typeStatusDescr: string;
    }

    export class TypeStatusesModel{
        type: TypeModel;
        status: StatusModel;
    }


let typeStatuses: TypeStatusesModel[] = [];
let typeStatusFirst: TypeStatusesModel= new TypeStatusesModel();
typeStatusFirst = {
  type: {
   typeID:1,
   typeDescription: "Description Type 1"
  },
  status: {
   typeId: 1,
   statusId: 1,
   typeStatusDescr: "Description Status 1"
  }
}
typeStatuses.push(typeStatusFirst);

let typeStatusSecond: TypeStatusesModel= new TypeStatusesModel();
typeStatusSecond= {
  type: {
   typeID:2,
   typeDescription: "Description Type 2"
  },
  status: {
   typeId: 1;
   statusId: 2;
   typeStatusDescr: "Description Status 2";
  }
}
typeStatuses.push(typeStatusSecond);
```

The problem is when i try to change the property `typeID` of the second object in typeStatuses array to number `2` that change the same property (`typeID`) in my first object. I try to create a temp object and to replace the "broken one" but nothing.( `let tempObject = Object.create(typeStatuses[1])`)

Comment: That's pretty unlikely. Can you show us the code you're using to change the property? Also, you're creating a class and then just creating an anonymous object. Instead of class, you likely want to use an interface instead.

Comment: You have a wrong semicolons  in that code. type: 1; ... should be type:1, ...

Answer (score 0):

You have some wrong semicolon that should be just coma. I would also change those clases for just interfaces as they are just declaring the properties without any behaivour.

```
export class TypeModel{
        typeID: number;
        typeDescription: string;
    }


    export class StatusModel{
        typeId: number;
        statusId: number;
        typeStatusDescr: string;
    }

    export class TypeStatusesModel{
        type: TypeModel;
        status: StatusModel;
    }


let typeStatuses: TypeStatusesModel[] = [];
let typeStatusFirst: TypeStatusesModel= new TypeStatusesModel();
typeStatusFirst = {
  type: {
   typeID:1,
   typeDescription: "Description Type 1"
  },
  status: {
   typeId: 1,
   statusId: 1,
   typeStatusDescr: "Description Status 1"
  }
}
typeStatuses.push(typeStatusFirst);

let typeStatusSecond: TypeStatusesModel= new TypeStatusesModel();
typeStatusSecond= {
  type: {
   typeID:2,
   typeDescription: "Description Type 2"
  },
  status: {
   typeId: 1,
   statusId: 2,
   typeStatusDescr: "Description Status 2",
  }
}
typeStatuses.push(typeStatusSecond);
typeStatuses[0].type.typeID=234;
console.log(JSON.stringify(typeStatuses));
```

it does work with a console log

> [{"type":{"typeID":234,"typeDescription":"Description Type
>   1"},"status":{"typeId ":1,"statusId":1,"typeStatusDescr":"Description
>   Status 1"}},{"type":{"typeID":2, "typeDescription":"Description Type
>   2"},"status":{"typeId":1,"statusId":2,"typeS tatusDescr":"Description
>   Status 2"}}]

So the code should be something like. I have also removed the export as I can't see you are using the interfaces outsite.

```
 interface TypeModel{
        typeID: number;
        typeDescription: string;
    }


    interface StatusModel{
        typeId: number;
        statusId: number;
        typeStatusDescr: string;
    }

    interface TypeStatusesModel{
        type: TypeModel;
        status: StatusModel;
    }


let typeStatuses: TypeStatusesModel[] = [];
let typeStatusFirst: TypeStatusesModel;
typeStatusFirst = {
  type: {
   typeID:1,
   typeDescription: "Description Type 1"
  },
  status: {
   typeId: 1,
   statusId: 1,
   typeStatusDescr: "Description Status 1"
  }
}
typeStatuses.push(typeStatusFirst);

let typeStatusSecond: TypeStatusesModel;
typeStatusSecond= {
  type: {
   typeID:2,
   typeDescription: "Description Type 2"
  },
  status: {
   typeId: 1,
   statusId: 2,
   typeStatusDescr: "Description Status 2",
  }
}
typeStatuses.push(typeStatusSecond);
typeStatuses[0].type.typeID=234;
console.log(JSON.stringify(typeStatuses));
```

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, because that's not the actual code and i write the example here.

Comment: @VSmolyanski Please test the examples before posting it here. It makes it *very* difficult to diagnose your problem (especially since you're claiming it's behaving in an extremely unlikely way). Your post still contains invalid semi colons even after the edit. Please test your snippet, fix it, and edit a working and reproducible example into your post.